# NodeJS fs.appendFile not working within promise in mocha

Tags: node.js, promise, mocha.js, fs

I want to keep a log during my integration test suite. I'm testing that every 'item' is being compiled and logging how much time it took. I'm using **node 4.3**.

First of all I create the log file:

```
before(function() {
    if (!fs.existsSync("./log.csv")) {
        fs.writeFile("./log.csv", "Name; Time");
    }
});
```

Then within each `it` block I would do this:

```
for (const item of items) {    
    it('compiles', function() {
        return item.testCompile();
    });
}
```

And `item` class has these methods:

```
testCompile() {
    return this
        .buildItem()
        .then(result => {
            // whatever testing stuff
        });
}

buildItem() {
    return this
        .internalLogicForCompiling()
        .then(result => {
            // This is not appending anything 
            fs.appendFile("./log.csv", `${item.name}; ${result.compileTime}`);

            return result;
        });
}
```

So far the file is created but never updated... Any clue what I'm doing wrong?

PS: I assume if the file doesn't exists, `fs` should throw an error, however it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is generally ignoring the fact that your `fs` calls are asynchronous. Promises are not magic. If you use code that is asynchronous but does not use promises, you need to do more than plop that code in a promise can call it done.

The easiest way to deal with the issue would be to use `fs.writeFileSync` and `fs.appendFileSync` instead of the calls you make. Otherwise, you should write your `before` like this:

```
before(function(done) {
    if (!fs.existsSync("./log.csv")) {
        fs.writeFile("./log.csv", "Name; Time", done);
    }
});
```

I've just added the `done` callback.

And `buildItem` could be something like this so that the promise it returns won't resolve before `appendFile` is done doing its work:

```
buildItem() {
    return this
        .internalLogicForCompiling()
        .then(result => {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                fs.appendFile("./log.csv", `${item.name}; ${result.compileTime}`, (err) => {
                    if (err) {
                        reject(err);
                        return;
                    }
                    resolve(result);
                });
            });
        });
}
```

Comment: Hi, the `return` I had it already. Syncs method seem to work OK :)